# Keeping 2 objects within cameras view

Tags: unity, camera

I have two object to control and I wanted to keep them at cameras view without adjusting the cameras size but the camera can move only in positive y-axis meaning ones it goes up it shouldn't move down but it's okay if one object gets out of bounds. Since its 2D the camera is Orthographic view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't make the camera view larger, then just set the camera's y position halfway between the two objects'

```
cameraY = (obj1Y +obj2Y) / 2
```

To make it stop at y = 0, use Mathf.Max:

```
cameraY = Mathf.Max(obj1Y + obj2Y, 0) / 2
```

This won't work if the camera can't display the two objects at once because they're too far apart